# How to prevent a "longpress" touch event listener from being called for a "touch up" event as well?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, touch-event

I have the following event listener for an object.

```js
canvas.on('touch:longpress', (e) => {
    // Some Code
});
```

This listener is called after the long press and called for "touch up" event as well. Why is this happening and how can this be bypassed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  var isTouching = false;
  canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
    console.log('touchstart');
    isTouching = true;
  });
  canvas.on('touch:longpress', function (e) {
    if (isTouching) {
      // Some Code
      console.log('longpress');
    }
  });
  canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
    console.log('touchend');
    isTouching = false;
  });
```

You can solve this situation with a boolean variable.